# How to create an instance store backed AMI for a windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I was able to do it for Linux instance using ec2-bundle-volume and was able to upload the same to S3. But any help for windows instances? I am not able to create a windows instance with root device type as instance store.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Instance Store-backed AMIs are a holdover from before the days of Amazon EBS. Aside from saving a few cents on EBS storage, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that it meets the [requirements listed in the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_InstanceStoreBacked_WinAMI.html), in particular:

> The only Windows AMIs that can be backed by instance store are those
>   for Windows Server 2003. Instance store-backed instances don't have
>   the available disk space required for later versions of Windows Server

If still not working check the doc listed and let us know what part of the process is failing.